# How to count occurrences in a dataframe columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, count

This is a sample of my df:

```
Paid    Scheduled   tfl modeName
True    True    True    bus
True    True    True    cable-car
True    True    False   coach
False   False   False   cycle
True    False   True    cycle-hire
True    True    True    dlr
```

I need to have in another dataframe only the modeName which are true in Paid and Scheduled:

```
modeName     
bus
cable car
coach
dlr
```

And count how many are paid AND scheduled. I got this with this code:

```
df1_transporte = df1.isFarePaying.values.sum() & df1.isScheduledService.values.sum()

df1_transporte
```

But how to get the modeNames that have both conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pandas,

you can use `df[(df['Paid']==True) & (df['Scheduled']==True)]` to generate a dataframe with only the rows where 'Paid' and 'Scheduled' are True.